# SQL & PHP - Selecionar tudo usando where

Tags: php, mysql

Estou fazendo um sistema de filtro bem simples usando `PHP` e `mysql`.

```
$stmt = $conexao->prepare("select * from filme where genero = '$genero'");
```

Eu estou querendo colocar uma na lista de gêneros que, quando selecionada, exibe todos os filmes.

Sei que eu conseguiria fazer isso facilmente usando if/else:

```
if ($genero == "todos"){
   $stmt = $conexao->prepare("select * from filme");
}else{
   $stmt = $conexao->prepare("select * from filme where genero = '$genero'");
}
```

Mas queria saber se tem alguma outra maneira de fazer isso caso o sistema fique muito mais complexo e o if/else fique grande demais. Por exemplo, se quisesse filtrar os filmes também por ano de lançamento, diretor e classificação indicativa, tudo ao mesmo tempo e com a mesma opção de exibir todos.

Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Desde já agradeço as respostas

Comment: O que você pode ir fazendo é concatenando a query enquanto o filtro for sendo selecionado. Se caso não tiver filtro vai fazer o select apenas do select básico

Comment: @gabrielfalieri Eu não entendi muito bem, será que você poderia me explicar melhor?

Comment: Breno, vamos supor. Como você faz para poder saber que o "generos" foi selecionado?

Comment: No html tem uma tag select com todos os gêneros cadastrados, aí quando o valor é alterado o programa executa um ajax que passa ele por url, pelo menos é isso q eu fiz

Answer (score 3):

> se quisesse filtrar os filmes também por ano de lançamento, diretor e classificação indicativa, tudo ao mesmo tempo e com a mesma opção de exibir todos

Se você quiser fazer *tudo junto*, ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
$stmt = $conexao->prepare("select * from filme where genero = '$genero' and lancamento = '$lancamento' and diretor = '$diretor' and classificacao = '$classificacao'");
```

Você pode ainda montar essa *query* de forma mais dinâmica:

```
// Exemplos:
$genero = 'acao';
$lancamento = '2018';
$diretor = 'Stallone';
$classificacao = 18;

$sql = "select * from filme where ";
if(isset($genero))
    $buscando[] = "genero = '".$genero."'";
if(isset($lancamento))
    $buscando[] = "lancamento = '".$lancamento."'";
if(isset($diretor))
    $buscando[] = "diretor = '".$diretor."'";
if(isset($classificacao))
    $buscando[] = "classificacao = '".$classificacao."'";

$sql .= join(' and ', $buscando);
$sql .= ';';

$stmt = $conexao -> prepare($sql); // select * from filme where genero = 'acao' and lancamento = '2018' and diretor = 'Stallone' and classificacao = '18';
```

Comment: obrigado, ajudou bastante

Answer (score 2):

Você pode automatizar isso usando $_GET ou montando um array:

Exemplo:

```
$filtro = ["ano" => "2018", "diretor"=> "Stalonne"];
$where = "";
foreach($filtro as $key => $value){
    $where .= $key." = '".$value."' AND ";
}
$where = substr($where, 0, -4);
$stmt = $conexao->prepare("select * from filme ".$where);
```

Essa string ficaria assim:

```
select * from filme ano = '2018' AND diretor = 'Stalonne'
```

Desta forma fica mais fácil até para refatorar quando for necessário.